# Javascript Arrow functions with 'this'

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

friends, a question on arrow functions, saying you can’t use **this** with arrow functions and it also has a lexical scope.
Can you explain why these two rules do not work here
With comments on the code please
Thanks

```js
let group1 = {
  title: 'Our Group',
  students: ['John', 'Pete', 'Alice'],
  showList() {
    this.students.forEach((student) =>
      console.table(this.title + ': ' + student)
    );
  },
};
 
let group2 = {
  title: 'Our Group2',
  students: ['Ann', 'Kate', 'Alice'],
};
group1.showList();
 
group1.showList.call(group2);
```

Comment: You _can_ use `this` inside a `=>`-style function, it just behaves differently to a `function`-function.

Comment: "*saying you can’t use this with arrow functions*" where is that coming from? You *can*. "*and it also has a lexical scope*" and that one is also true. That's why you can use `this`. "*Can you explain why these two rules do not work here*" how do they "not work"? The first one is nonsense, the second one works exactly as described. What's the actual issue you face?

Comment: I'm beginer in Javascrtipt becouse of this i asked this quation.